# ClientResource null attributes

Tags: java, restlet

I have an issue with `ClientResource`. When I initialize, the attributes are `null`.

```
String url = "..."
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(url);
```

`clientResource.getRequestAttributes()` produces `null`.

This produces a problem for me to add custom headers to my call.

Btw, there is a reason that `clientResource.getHeaders` is not present at `ClientResource` API? I'm working with **Restlet** version 2.3.1 here is my pom:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>maven-restlet</id>
    <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the following code to add a custom header:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://...");
cr.getRequest().getHeaders().add("MyCustomHeader", "some value");
```

**Edit**

If the `getHeaders` method doesn't exist for the version of Restlet you use, replace it by the following code:

```
Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) cr.getAttributes().get(
            HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
    cr.getAttributes().put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, headers);
}

headers.add("MyCustomHeader", "some value");
```

Comment: the thing is that getHeaders() does not exists

Comment: Which version of Restlet do you use? This method was introduced in latest versions... I edited my answer with the code to use in this case.

Comment: My solution was exactly as you wrote now :) As I wrote in my question, I use 2.3.1

Comment: Cool ;-) That's strange since I can see this message into version 2.3.1. See https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/2.3.1/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/Message.java#L265